# mp4 videos and javascript

Tags: javascript, video

I have problems with javascript blugins like

```
http://jplayer.org/
```

and

```
MediaElement.js
```

that cannot play videos over 500mb. I have some videos over 1 GB-s.
What javascript blugins are able to play many-hours videos from internet and work well in all known browsers (IE, Firefox, Grome, Safary, Opera, Spartan, ..)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some further information about the context of your application? For instance, could it be a transmission problem that is not related with the mentioned plugins? what happens if you try to play the files?
Did you try to play the files in a native html code, e.g.

```
<video controls autobuffer preload="metadata">
<source src="myfile" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Another issue could be the way of preparing the mp4-files. Take a look at a previous [post](https://superuser.com/questions/438390/creating-mp4-videos-ready-for-http-streaming).

Last but not least such large files can become a problem for the browser itself.

PS: Who is downvoting all the video related questions?